# Index "catalog_product_flat" disappeared after update to 1.9x

Tags: product, catalog, reindex, index, flat

After updating from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.1 the catalog_product_flat index is not longer shown.

The index is neither shown in Magento Backend nor if i call

```
php shell/indexer.php info
```

It is activated under System > Config > Catalog > Catalog > Shop

I can still call it directly via

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
```

and the database tables are filled and used.

Any idea how it comes or to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is an old version of Miravisit AsyncIndex extension. If I deactivate it, the catalog product index appears. If the extension is active, the index is hidden.

Comment: An update of the extension fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That might be because your Flat Catalog Product and Flat Catalog Category is set to No in admin panel

> System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend

Use Flat Catalog Category
Use Flat Catalog Product

Change this settings to Yes and check indexing page

Comment: No, it is activated for both.

Comment: Have you cleared cache ?

Comment: Of course :) Many times. Only catalog_product_flat is not available. catalog_category_flat shown as normal.